# Is it possible to filter DataView by column instead of by Row

Tags: c#

Is there something like DataView.ColumnFilter instead of DataView.RowFilter ?

Comment: Can you explain further?  For what purpose?  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

A little late, but I was looking for a way to filter / hide some columns in a dataView as well and did it like this:

DataView.Table.Columns["ColumnName"].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;

Works fine.

Comment: Exactly what I have been looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You filter a row with column restraints....

```
DataView.RowFilter = "columnName = value"
```

This will effectively filter your DataView by the column for each row where the column restraint is met.

Comment: That's not what I mean. I mean hide column.

Comment: You wouldn't/can't hide the column via the dataview. You would simply hide the column in the gridview that is displaying the results or any other item that is using the dataview for it's datasource.

Answer (score -1):

Had to reply to this as been looking for ages and drawing a blank.

You CAN hide a column from a dataview:

```
dv.Table.Columns.Remove("colname")
```

Comment: Isn't that removing the column from the underlying table, and not from the dataview?